# A group containing an ellipse is rotated about an arbitrary axis, how to get the x and y distance the ellipse on the group changed?

Tags: java, math, javafx-2

I have a Group with an Ellipse on it. The Group is rotated around an arbitrary point (by adding a Rotate instance to the Groups transforms). How do I find out what distance (x and y) the Ellipse (the center) changed? The center properties of the ellipse don't change, since the transformation is applied to the group.

I'm guessing this can be solved mathematically or by toying around with the transform instances on the Group/Ellipse, however, in both areas I don't have much expertise and don't seem to arrive to a correct result.

```
import javafx.animation.Transition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.GroupBuilder;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SceneBuilder;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.PaneBuilder;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.EllipseBuilder;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.RectangleBuilder;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.RotateBuilder;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Ellipse e = EllipseBuilder.create().centerX(110).centerY(110).radiusX(5).radiusY(5).style("-fx-fill: green;").build();
    Rectangle r = RectangleBuilder.create().x(100).y(100).width(30).height(30).style("-fx-fill: red;").build();
    Group group = GroupBuilder.create().children(r, e).build();

    Ellipse pivot = EllipseBuilder.create().centerX(60).centerY(100).radiusX(2).radiusY(2).style("-fx-fill: purple;").build();

    Pane p = PaneBuilder.create().children(group, pivot).build();

    Scene scene = SceneBuilder.create().root(p).width(200).height(200).build();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    final Rotate rotate = RotateBuilder.create().pivotX(pivot.getCenterX()).pivotY(pivot.getCenterY()).build();
    group.getTransforms().add(rotate);

    RotationTransition trans = new RotationTransition(rotate.angleProperty());
    trans.playFromStart();
}

class RotationTransition extends Transition {
    private final DoubleProperty angle;

    public RotationTransition(DoubleProperty angle) {
        this.angle = angle;
        setCycleDuration(Duration.seconds(5));
    }

    @Override
    protected void interpolate(double frac) {
        angle.setValue(frac * 60);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

The above code shows an animation of rotation. How do I find out what x and y distance the green ellipse changed after the rotation? Or, equally, how do I find out the new coordinates of the ellipse?

Comment: Could you attach a code, for us to be able to play with it?

Comment: I have edited the question to include a visual example.

Comment: group.localToParent(e.getCenterX(), e.getCenterY())? Seems to give the correct new coordinates of the ellipse..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I still have trouble understanding the various localToParent, parentToLocal, etc methods in complex scenario's (multiple nested groups with different transforms), I found through some experimantion that in the posted code example

```
group.localToParent(e.getCenterX(), e.getCenterY())
```

seems to work. In my actual application I'm only interested in the distance moved and not the actual location, so the same method works there. (although it probably doesn't give a meaningful absolute number considering my complex hierarchy of groups).

Comment: I was thinking about the same. Bounds in local, bounds in parent, etc - there is some set of methods about actual and relative bounds understanding, which should be explored (I cannot remember what are they about).